# Unknown image format for png

Tags: node.js, image, pdfkit

I am using node JS, express and SQL Server to develop a website. I store signatures as png images in the database as VARBINARY(MAX). I use pdfkit to display these signatures on a pdf that gets created. On my home computer it works, but when I try to continue developing on my work computer it says "Unknown image format". The code I use to load and convert the image is:

```
const resultSigns = await pool.request()
    .input('IncidentID', Number(req.body.id))
    .execute(`Read_IncidentSignatures_SP`);
const signatures = resultSigns.recordset;

let sign1 = '';
let sign2 = '';

for (const sign of signatures) {
    if (sign.SignaturePos === 1) {
        // ...
    } else if (sign.SignaturePos === 2) {
        sign2 = convertToImage(sign.Signature);
    } 
}

function convertToImage(data) {
    if (data === undefined || data === '') {
        return '';
    }
    var originalBase64ImageStr = new Buffer.from(data).toString('utf8');
    var decodedImage = new Buffer.from(originalBase64ImageStr , 'base64');
    return decodedImage;
}
```

In the pdfkit code I use:

```
if (sign2 !== '') {
    doc.image(sign2, 287, 660, { scale: 0.20 });
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?